# How to POST in Flutter with cookie or session?

Tags: http, post, oauth-2.0, dart, flutter

I'm trying to send a post request in Flutter with http.

and I want to use OAuth2 to login to a self hosted WordPress installation.

At the first request it goes success and I get login and get cookie. But in the second request i try to set responded cookie in the header and get token but response is 302 and I think cookie or session don't set in the header or something like this.

Swift working version:

https://github.com/wlcdesigns/iOS-WP-OAuth/blob/master/iOS%20WP%20OAuth/OAuthWP.swift

Here is the request:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';

ajaxPost() async {

    String apiURL = "http://example.com/app/oauth/authorize";
    String username = 'admin';
    String password = 'pass';

    final identifier = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    final secret = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

    var requestBody = {
      'client_id': identifier,
      "user_login": username,
      "user_password": password,
      'wpoauth_login': "1",
    };

    var headers = {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };

    Response r = await post(
      apiURL,
      body: requestBody,
      headers: headers
    );
    print(r.statusCode);
    print(r.body);

    var reqBody = {
      'client_id': identifier,
      'ios_wp_oauth': '1',
      'response_type': 'code',
    };

    String rawCookie = r.headers['set-cookie'];
    if (rawCookie != null) {
      int index = rawCookie.indexOf(';');
      headers['cookie'] =
          (index == -1) ? rawCookie : rawCookie.substring(0, index);
    }

    Response res = await post(
      apiURL,
      body: reqBody,
      headers: headers
    );

    print(res.statusCode);
    print(res.body);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [requests](https://github.com/jossef/requests)

- as of now, it uses [shared_preferences](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/shared_preferences) which is not the best practice (security-wise) to store sensitive data (session-ids etc) [Issue #1](https://github.com/jossef/requests/issues/1)

pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
  requests: ^1.0.0
```

Usage:

```
import 'package:requests/requests.dart';

ajaxPost() async {
    // this will persist cookies
    await Requests.post("http://example.com/app/oauth/authorize", body: {"username":"...", "password":"..."} ); 

    // next requests will re-use the persisted cookies
    dynamic data = await Requests.get("http://example.com/app/foo", json: true); 
}
```

Comment: BTW - I strongly recommend that you use https

Comment: It doesn't support MultipartFile request and this is basic need.

Comment: @Sateesh - it's not a reason downvote. you can open a PR in my repo if a specific feature is missing

Comment: Okay, I will undo the downvote. I have refactored whole code that was dependent on `Requests` and unfortunately I have used `Dio`

Comment: @Jossef Harush Hello)) Sorry, I didn't use your package yet, but the question is: How did you handle parralel requests? Because they both updating cookie. Do you freeze second request till first one will end?

Comment: Did you stop maintaining the package? Doesnt work anymore

Comment: @West - Didn't stop but I'm super busy today than in 2019 :) Please check https://github.com/jossef/requests and use the latest examples, things got refactored a bit since v1.0.0. Also check the issues page and report a new one